# How to combine multiple If conditions in C

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison

I have code like this in C:

```
if (count == 5 || count == 8 || count == 9 || count == 10)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Is there a possibility to write this shorter?
Something like:

```
if (count == 5, 8, 9, 10)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to insert a comma-separated list into an `if` statement itself as in your example, but you may write something like this to use the comma-separated list format.

```
int allowed_counts[] = {5, 8, 9, 10};
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (count == allowed_counts[i]) {
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Although, a switch statement is more computationally efficient for all list sizes.

Comment: @Gugi: Depending on what you're doing, the straightforward `if` statement in your question might be the best way to do it. It's more readable than most of the alternatives, and for something this small performance isn't likely to be a significant issue.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how many different values and different branches you have it can sometimes be neater/easier to use a switch:

```
switch (count)
{
case 5:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
    do_something();
    break;
default:
    do_something_else();
    break;
}
```

Comment: I have just my 4 values. Just wanted to shorten the code. count is max. 16.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, it can make sense to use a bit map.

For example, your test:

```
if (count == 5 || count == 8 || count == 9 || count == 10)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ((1<<count) & 0x720)
```

The values 5, 8, 9, and 10 are encoded in the bits of the value `0x720`.

Typically this would make sense if you have meaningful symbolic constants for the values 5, 8, 9, and 10, with `0x720` constructed from a bitwise "or" (`|`) of those constants -- which would result in more verbose code than the simple `if` you have in your question.

In practice, real-world code should minimize the use of "magic numbers". It's difficult to tell what the values 5, 8, 9, and 10 mean.

Possibly you should consider using a different algorithm, but it's impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: Yes, maybe there is a better solution to my problem, but it doesn't matter since this is just a small piece from my programming homework, and i dont want to post the whole task.

Comment: To avoid undefined behaviour, only do this if it is known that `count < 31` ! (or whatever your int size is)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

So the condition is testing if count is 5, 8, 9, 10:

```
if (count == 5 || (count >= 8 && count <= 10 ))
    printf("count is 5, 8, 9 or 10");
```

Comment: Unless `count` equals 6 or 7!

Comment: @Rizier123: The original code wanted only 5, 8, 9 and 10 to succeed at the conditional. Your code also succeeds at 6 and 7.

Comment: @Rizier123: No, it doesn't.  Try it yourself, with `count == 6`. The code in the question tests for `count` equal to `5`, `8`, `9`, or `10`, *not* for a range.

Comment: yes, this would work, but it's just a bit better, i wanted something very short and for every scenario. so it should also work when count is 4,6, 8, or 11.

Comment: @SimonGuggi i don't think you can get that spesific condition any smaller! (What you mean it also should work if `count` is 4,6,8 or 11? You mean in the condition that the same should happen like if count is 5?)

Comment: yes, you are right, it's really very small. but not really better readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

E.g `EXIST(count, (5,8,9,10)` expand by macro of boost

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>

#define F(r, data, i, elem) BOOST_PP_IF(i, ||, ) (data == elem)
#define EXIST(var, values) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(F, var , BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(values) )

int main(){
    int count;
    scanf("%d", &count);
    if(EXIST(count, (5,8,9,10)))//if( (count == 5) || (count == 8) || (count == 9) || (count == 10) )
        printf("yes\n");
    else
        printf("no\n");
    return 0;
}
```